# Firestore to BigQuery using Cloud function

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a Bigquery table that link using the firestore to bigQuery extension. But, I want the BigQuery to run based on the event trigger from cloud firestore (e.g. if there is any changes/new document inserted in specific collection) so that it can load the new data streaming direct to BigQuery table.

And I want all the cloud function to be written using Python script. But most of the online use case/examples are in JS (example: https://blog.questionable.services/article/from-firestore-to-bigquery-firebase-functions/).

When I tried to follow (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) and deploy in cloud function as below, it keep fails.

```
import json


cred = credentials.Certificate("YYYYY.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="YYYYY.json"

db = firestore.client()
bq = bigquery.Client()

collection = db.collection('XXXX')
def hello_firestore(data, context):
    """ Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
        data (dict): The event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    trigger_resource = context.resource

    print ('Function triggered by change to: %s' % trigger_resource)

    print ('\nOld value:')
    print (json.dumps(data["oldValue"]))

    print ('\nNew value:')
    print (json.dumps(data["value"]))
```

Request for ideas/suggestion. Thank you for clarifying me in advance.

Comment: Does the deployment fail with any error message in particular?

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you for your reply. So far it just says user source code error, and i'm not sure whether the above code is correctly coded.

Comment: Try deploying your app with the [gcloud functions deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) command and use the `--verbosity=debug` flag, this should give more insights on what is causing the deployment to fail.